# Read unique data from table and process it distributed manner

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hash, spring-batch, distributed-computing

All I have to design a new service which will cover the following.

1. Read all rows from a table
2. Process business logic
3. Call another API
4. Process response.

Now if it is a single instance system It will be an easy process. Now I have to design it in a distributed system.

In a distributed system, I will have multiple instances and I want each instance process unique record.

How to achieve the above scenario. I am thinking of hash base approach like while fetching record but this is not covering every use case.

I have more than one instance of application are running. How i make sure that each instance gets unique record

Comment: Have a look at https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow

Comment: How above approach work in distributed system.

Comment: How do you operate the distributed system?

Comment: My concern is that if we have multiple instances are running Then how will I make sure that each instance gets different data

Comment: And my question is how are you starting the multiple instances?

Comment: We are deploying application in AWS and there we setting min-max instance property..